# Linking to subclasses - one works, the other doesn't

Tags: c#, subclass

For the last part of my assignment due today, I have to instantiate a base class and two subclasses that I generated earlier. While I'm pretty sure how I'd go about instantiating them, I'm running into an error early on:

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using ClassLibrary2;
using ClassLibrary3;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Tennis aTennis;
        private Football aFootball;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Tennis and Football are the two subclasses, and I have verified that the layout in those classes is the same. However, only "Football aFootball" is recognized by VS as a subclass, "Tennis aTennis" brings up a:

> "namespace could not be found"

...error.  Is this an error in this application or with the Tennis class itself?

EDIT: Tennis and Football code, as follows:

Tennis:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
   public class Tennis :  Team
    {
       private string assistantname;
        public  Tennis(  )  :  base  (  )
        {
        }
        public Tennis(string sport, string cname, int pamount,
        int anAge, string asname)
        :base(sport,  cname,  pamount, anAge)
        {
            assistantname = asname;
        }
        public string Assistantname
        {
            get
            {
                return assistantname;
            }
        }
        public override int GetSeasonMonths()
        {
            return 3;
        }
        public int CallOverriddenGetSeasonMonths()
        {
            return base.GetSeasonMonths();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "The training assistant's name is" + assistantname;
        }
    }
}
```

Football:

```
namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    public class Football : Team
    {
        private string mascot;
        public Football()
            : base()
        {
        }
        public Football(string sport, string cname, int pamount,
        int anAge, string mcot)
            : base(sport, cname, pamount, anAge)
        {
            mascot = mcot;
        }
        public string Mascot
        {
            get
            {
                return mascot;
            }
        }
        public override int GetSeasonMonths()
        {
            return 3;
        }
        public int CallOverriddenGetSeasonMonths()
        {
            return base.GetSeasonMonths();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "The team mascot is the" + mascot;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code for `Tennis` and `FootBall`

Comment: Do you have a reference to the assembly (project) that `Tennis` is in?

Comment: @Tim Yes, and to the base class as well.

Comment: Does the assembly with `Tennis` in it build successfully?   I'm expecting it does, but let's rule out the simple stuff first :)

Comment: @Tim Yes, the Tennis assembly builds successfully.

Comment: @AB - What happens if you replace `private Tennis aTennis;` with `private ClassLibrary2.Tennis aTennis;` in the main class?

Comment: @Tim Now it's "The type or namespace name 'Tennis' does not exist in the namespace 'ClassLibrary2' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Tim It turns out Tennis had not been rebuilt after I had edited it, so the instantiator was expecting a different class name in the private Tennis aTennis statement. Works now.